# .slideToggle is not a Function - jquery

Tags: jquery

Aware this is a common question but I can't see the fix.
I'm getting

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).parent(...).find(...).slideToggle is not a
>   function

```js
$('.mobile-button').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().find('.mobile').slideToggle();
  $(this).toggleClass('open');

  $(this).parent().siblings().children().next().slideUp();
  $(this).parents().siblings().find('.mobile-button').removeClass('open');
  return false;
});
```

```css
.open:after {
  transform: translateY(-150%) rotate(225deg);
  transition: transform .5s ease;
  -ms-transform: translateY(-150%) rotate(225deg);
  -moz-transition: transform .5s ease;
  -moz-transform: translateY(-150%) rotate(225deg);
  -webkit-transition: transform .5s ease;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-150%) rotate(225deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.js"></script>
<section class="agreement__events-mobile">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="agreement__event">
      <button class="agreement__events-header mobile-button"></button>
      <div class="mobile"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I think it has to do with it not finding the object but not sure of the fix. Any help?

Comment: What version of jquery do you use?

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen 3.4.1 slim

Comment: The slim branch of jQuery has lots of methods removed, primarily related to AJAX and animations. You will need to use the full version of jQuery for your code to work

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks didn't think it could be that! gone for the full version and all working!